# Steps to implement referral url functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and web development. Trying to figure out steps to implement referral. Using Codeigniter for MVC. I googled a lot and tried to find a tutorial but no luck.

1. User's referral url will be http://mysite.com/?ref=primarykey_of_user
2. A user's friend uses referral url to access mysite. I will read referral url from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` in the `index()` of default controller
3. Extract primary_key of the first user from the url to use it later.

Does it sound safe? Should I include any other step or do it in a different way?.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER`can easily be spoofed, but unless the value of this is not critical, I would go for this solution. In 99% of all cases, noone would tamper with the referer anyways.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER has nothing to do with "referral urls" in the sense you're using.  With your example referal url, `$_GET['ref']` would contain the string you want (`primarykey_of_user`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any security issue you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're tracking a referral, you don't need the `HTTP_REFERER` anyway, aside from knowing where they came from. However, it can be falsified (while unlikely) so if you're ever going to use that data you need to be sure to filter it, etc.

Having an identification for the referring "person" is smart but you don't want to use the primary key - you should add some sort of randomly generated, unique identification code so that people can't guess it.

How you generate the code is up to you - you just need to randomly generate a string of characters:

```
   public function makePassword($length = 5){
        $password = "";
        $possible = "0123456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz";
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $length) {
            $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            if (!strstr($password, $char)) {
                $password .= $char;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $password;
    }
```

Use that generated code to associate someone with a database record. This way I can't assume that if I'm referrer #1, I can find out the id for #2, etc.

Comment: Using primary key in referal URLs isn't necessarily a huge risk.  SO does it.  My "Share" URL for your answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/15775498/82769 ; 82769 is my user id (15775498 is your answer id).  What's the risk of users guessing each others referral urls?  Giving away free referrals to other users?

Comment: It depends on the application. In referral URLs it's not really a big deal but it all depends on where the data is used. As long as your app makes sure that someone isn't accessing data through an ID that isn't theirs, you're OK. Our referral system uses these same short codes for API authentication too, so it's a just little bit safer than IDs. However, you're right, when the ID points only to something that's public and not some private page, it's ok.